# Does closing the descriptor affect the daemon process created

Tags: c, linux

I wanna create a daemon process, which runs the `top` command of Linux in the background.
If I closed all the descriptor, I can't find that `top` was created, because there is nothing about `top` when I use the `ps -aux` command to check.
If I removed the lines about closing the descriptor, the `top` will run at terminal.

What's wrong with my code?  If I wanna the program run correctly when closing the descriptor, what should I do?

This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main(void)
{
    int pid;
    int i;
    int fd;
    char *d[2];
    char a[5] = "top";
    d[0] = a;
    a[3] = '\0';
    d[1] = NULL;
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        perror("fork error");
    else if (pid > 0)
        exit(0);
    else {
        setsid();
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
            perror("fork error");
        else if (pid > 0)
            exit(0);
        else {
            for (i = 0;i < 255;i++)
                close(i);
            fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
            dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
            close(fd);
            chdir("/");
            umask(0);
            printf("%s\n", d[0]);
            execvp(d[0], d);
            perror("execvp failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's `top` going to show its output if you close all its file descriptors — or send them all to `/dev/null`?    Why would you run a program that displays information if the information can never be seen?

Comment: Note that the `printf()` just before the `execvp()` writes to `/dev/null`; so does the `perror()` if the `execvp()` fails.

Comment: I just want the program create a daemon ,  which can run a shell command in the background,I don't care the output of it.I chose the top command by chance, but it dose't work.

Comment: You could run `sleep 300` as an interim measure.  Eventually, you'll decide to run something which can be told where to log its output, etc — maybe an Apache `httpd` server, for example.

Comment: You could also try `strace -o /tmp/top.strace top` as the command to run; that will give you a file, `/tmp/top.strace` which shows you the system calls that `top` executes, and it will probably show it exiting, perhaps after writing some error message(s) to some places.  Similarly for any other command, of course.

Comment: I had read the manpage of strace, which I had't known before.It is a little complex for me , I will learn  how to using it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the stupid mistake I have made.I close all the descriptors and point the stdin,stdout,stdout to /dev/null.But the top command need the system information coming from the input.So the execvp faild, the top command doesn't execute.

If I don't close the descriptor 0 (stdin), the top command will execute in the background.If I close the descriptor 0 and point the descriptor 2 (stderr)to a log, the error will be print in the log.

It is too stubborn to think that the daemon process must close all descripotrs first .In case of wasting resource, we should just close the unecessary descripotrs.

From the top manpage:
"-b  :Batch-mode operation
            Starts top in 'Batch' mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will  not  accept  input"

The top command can execute without input ,using argument -b, and this works in my code .

Thanks very much.

Comment: Normally a daemon should just do that (close file descriptors). Your answer makes sense because top simply isn't a daemon but an interactive program. The standard approach to run such a program in the background would be to connect it through double pipes to a controlling process.